# How to call salary rule in python code odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11, odoo-12

I want to use salary rule in python code for some calculations. 
Anyone please tell me how can I do it?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What are you trying at the time?

Comment: Actually  have no idea, how to call a salary rule in any python code method.

Answer (score 0):

If you know anything about your rule, i.e "name", you can try something like:

```
def _get_salary_rule(self):
  rule = self.env['hr.salary.rule'].search([('name', '=', 'SALARY_RULE_NAME')])
  return rule
```